# How to programmatically perform approximations on SageMath

Tags: symbolic-math, sage

Starting with an example, consider the following expression

```
sage: EX=h/(h-z)
sage: EX

  h  
─────
h - z
```

Let's say I want to make the approximation `h>>z`. This would yield the result that `EX ~ 1`. So, how do I achieve this result on SageMath?

For now all I can do is just to stop, and manually rewrite something like

```
# If h>>z
sage: EX_approx=1
```

Is there any way that I can modify such expressions automatically/programmatically in the code? Keeping in mind that this simple example is just an *example*, and I wanna be able to do this for any equation.

I've tried things like

```
EX(h>>z)
EX.assume(h>>z)
limit(EX, (h-z)=h)
```

The thing that works for some cases is

```
limit(EX, z=0)
```

but that's strictly not the same thing and it doesn't work for cases like this:

```
sage: EX2=integrate(z^2*exp(EX), z)
sage: EX2

                                  ⌠                          
                            h     ⎮                   h      
                          ─────   ⎮                 ─────    
  ⎛   2        2      3⎞  h - z   ⎮  ⎛   4    3  ⎞  h - z    
  ⎝3⋅h ⋅z + h⋅z  - 2⋅z ⎠⋅ℯ        ⎮ -⎝3⋅h  - h ⋅z⎠⋅ℯ         
- ───────────────────────────── - ⎮ ────────────────────── dz
                6                 ⎮    ⎛ 2            2⎞     
                                  ⎮  6⋅⎝h  - 2⋅h⋅z + z ⎠     
                                  ⌡                          
sage: limit(EX2, z=0)
1/2*h^3*e - 1/6*h^3*limit(integrate(z*e^(h/(h - z))/(h^2 - 2*h*z + z^2), z), z, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

An approximation to some order of a "small" parameter can be obtained with [`taylor`](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/constructions/calculus.html#power-series) method:

```
integrate(z^2*exp(EX).taylor(z, 0, 3), z)
```

returns

```
1/180*(60*h^3*z^3*e + 45*h^2*z^4*e + 54*h*z^5*e + 65*z^6*e)/h^3
```

Comment: But again you have to do it manually. I'm focusing more on an approach where `EX2` is obtain via other method (integrating an ODE, for example).